# I want to make the same automation as my iPhone and iPad on my MacBook

Tags: automator, automation

[image]

[image]

I want to make this automation of Shortcuts on my MacBook.
How can I make it?
I also want to make the opposite automation which is ‘Turn Night Shift On” when turning Personal Focus mode off.

Maybe should I use Automator on Mac? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a shortcut that turns on night shift and sets a focus in shortcuts. MacOS does not support Automations yet in Shortcuts.

First to do night shift, you need to install [nightlight](https://github.com/smudge/nightlight) through Homebrew. To install Homebrew run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`. If homebrew is already installed, you can skip this step.

To install nightlight, run `brew install smudge/smudge/nightlight`. You can turn night shift on and off by running `nightlight on` and `nightlight off` respectively.

To make your shortcut, open Shortcuts and create a new one. Title it "Focus with Night Shift On". Drag in a "Set Focus" and change the focus to "Personal" and "On until turned off". Then drag in a "Run Shell Script" and change it to

`PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`

`nightlight on`

When you run this, it will turn on Night Shift and your personal focus at the same time.

Now make a duplicate and change the settings to "Personal" and "Turn Focus Off" and rename it to "Focus with Night Shift Off". Change the code to

`PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`

`nightlight on`

Now drag the two shortcuts into the "Menu Bar" folder in the sidebar in Shortcuts. The shortcuts logo should appear in your menu bar. If it doesn't, press Cmd-, in Shortcuts, go to the Sidebar tab and make sure menu bar is checked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I should rather wait until Apple offcially releases automation function on shortcuts.